# I'm having hard time telling these two python codes apart

Tags: python-3.x

(1)

```
s = '357827351092'
l = []
for i in s:
    if int(i) > 5:
    l.append(i)
print(l)
```

(2)

```
s = '357827351092'
for i in s:
    l = []
    if int(i) > 5:
    l.append(i)
print(l)
```

The output of the first code is as expected but the second one prints an empty list. What made it empty?. I thought they would both have the same output.

Comment: Initialization of list again and again

Comment: In the first snippet you're creating a list *once*; in the second snippet you're creating a list in *every loop iteration*. So they're not equal.